# React Bootstrap Table show and update

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am able to get a react bootstrap table to show with hard coded values, but I am trying to get it to show on a button click and display values based on a parameter. Also, on a button click can I update that same table?

Comment: store your hardcoded values to the state. use that state to iterate the table. whenever you update the state the component will rerender & will take effect.